# How to store binary data in PHP

Tags: php

People know all about storing binary data in database server as BLOBs. How would one accomplish the same thing in PHP?

In other words, how do i store blobs in a php variable?

Comment: PHP can work with binary data as long as the function you're using on the data is binary safe, for example `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`. Always check the manual pages when in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PHP doesn't have Unicode support you can safely use normal strings as binary storage. Most (all?) functions are null-safe, too, so you shouldn't get any problems because of that either.

PS: Theoretically you could prefix all binary strings with `b` (e.g. `b'binary data'`). This is a forward compatability token to make sure that strings that expect to be handled as binary will really be handled so even than Unicode support is available.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with binary format, but is binary format always in blocks of 8bit? In that case, what happens if I have a format that uses numbers beyond 255? (Or is that used at all?)

Comment: @ultimatebuster: Yes, this is what people normally mean when talking about binary data: A sequence of bytes.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: Binary format is always in 8-bit bytes, yes. However, certain encodings (like UTF-8) use more than one byte to represent one letter. In that case the encoding is different but the "binary format" is still in the form of 8-bit bytes.

Comment: Does working with string have an advantage over just using arrays?

Comment: @ultimatebuster: In PHP it makes a big difference, especially in terms of memory usage. In PHP arrays are hash tables thus large array bucket and linked list structures must be allocated to store an element. Additionally zvals would need to be created for every byte. If you use a string on the other hand you will really need only one byte of storage per byte of binary data. PS: You can access strings just like normal arrays. `$str[7]` gives you character (or in your case the byte) at position 7.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: If you are only storing it (you didn't say you want to do anything else with it) then there is definitely no advantage to using arrays, strings are better.

Comment: *"As PHP doesn't have Unicode support..."* is a terribly misleading assertion. PHP supports Unicode perfectly fine, and that doesn't really have anything to do with the topic at hand. What you mean to say is that strings in PHP are dumb byte arrays which do not have an associated encoding. In other words, PHP strings *are* BLOBs.

Answer (score 1):

Easy - store it in a string.  You can use all the normal string functions (strlen, substr, etc) - just remember that the PHP string functions work in single byte units, e.g. `substr($binstr, 0, 1)` gives you the first 8 bits of `$binstr`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as an array of bytes. After all binary data is nothing more.